# Swift Xcode AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject encoding versus C# Xamarin AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

Tags: c#, swift, xcode, xamarin, character-encoding

I am researching for a Barcode scanning application with iOS iPhone Camera.

I can use Swift to get the string data that I actually need from the image I scan. However, when using Xamarin with the Xamarin implementation of the `AVFoundation.AVMetadataObject` and `AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject`, I don't get all of the characters. The C# code appears to execute in the same way as the Swift code with two different results.

Example Xcode Swift:

```
if let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first {
    guard let readableObject = metadataObject as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject else { return }
    guard let stringValue = readableObject.stringValue else { return }
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
    found(code: stringValue)
}
```

will render something like this: **WHICH I WANT**

*[)>\u{1e}06\u{1d}1SMYDATA\u{1d}S1MYDATA\u{1d}1PMYDATA\u{1d}WMYDATA\u{1d}4LUS\u{1e}\u{4}*

Example  Xamarin Foundation Code:

```
var barcodeMetadataObject = transformedMetadataObject as AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject;
if (barcodeMetadataObject != null)
{
    var barcodeOverlayPath = this.BarcodeOverlayPathWithCorners(barcodeMetadataObject.Corners);
            metadataObjectOverlayLayer.Path = barcodeOverlayPath;

    // If the metadata object has a string value, display it.
    string textLayerString = null;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(barcodeMetadataObject.StringValue))
    {
        textLayerString = barcodeMetadataObject.StringValue;
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: add Descriptor (line 618 in original iOS sample)
    }
```

will render something like this: **WHICH I DO NOT WANT...I WANT THE ENTIRE CHARACTER SET**

*[)>061SMYDATAS1911500531PMYDATAWMYDATA*

So I have this: (Xcode)
*[)>\u{1e}06\u{1d}1SMYDATA\u{1d}S1MYDATA\u{1d}1PMYDATA\u{1d}WMYDATA\u{1d}4LUS\u{1e}\u{4}*

Versus this:(Xamarin)
*[)>061SMYDATAS1911500531PMYDATAWMYDATA*

I am not understanding why the implementation in Xamarin would not be supplying all of the same characters of the scan when it essentially acts only as a wrapper.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Are you sure if the `metadataObject`  in swift is the same thing as `barcodeMetadataObject`  in c#?

Comment: I believe so, from the Xamarin.iOS repo example compared to the Xcode Swift Example  Swift Exmple **metadataObject as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject** versus the Xamarin.iOS Repo Example **var barcodeMetadataObject = transformedMetadataObject as AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject**. I just dont know the inner workings of the Xamarin Piece. I will examine the OpenSource implementation code of Xamarin, maybe that is where I should have looked.

Comment: So, you are looking [this sample](https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/tree/master/ios11/AVCamBarcode)?

Comment: Yes, I am looking at the **AVCamBarcode** sample. I found the solution to my issue lastnight. In Xamarin, the characters in DEBUG and Text Display are not visible like they in the Swift code. I forgot something I had done on an Android Barcode scanner for an Intermec Device, take the resulting string from ```c# textLayerString = barcodeMetadataObject.StringValue;``` and do textLayerString.toArray(). All data elements are visible so I can see the delimiters in the string. This is working now. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear that:).